# How to select 32 or 64 bit Informix Csdk 3.7?

Tags: informix, embedded-sql

My developer machine is a Windows 7 64bit and have some programs on 32 an others on 64 bits

since the upgrade of the 3.70FC3 and 3.70TC3, I'm having problems compiling with VisualStudio 2010 sp1.

maybe there is some configuration that I need to do to change 64 to 32 bit. Or maybe is not supported to have both csdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is feasible, you select which is in use by setting `$INFORMIXDIR` (oops; I mean `%INFORMIXDIR%`) to the correct directory and any other related changes (the correct `bin` subdirectory added to `%PATH%`, etc).

If there isn't an easy way to switch such variables, then it may not be feasible; I avoid working on Windows so I can't report of my own experience.  Classically, it was certainly expected that you would choose one version and stick with it.  On Unix, it has been possible to have both, but there isn't the registry to complicate things.